# Как при "эктиве" убрать текст?

Tags: css, html5

Есть сайдбар. Нужно чтоб при нажаитии на пункт меню текст изменялся на другой. Подскажите пожалуйста, как этого добиться?

```css
.sidebar > div:nth-child(1){
  margin: 16px 0 0 28px;
  background: url(../images/Open_Book.png) no-repeat;
  background-position: left 26px center;
}

.sidebar > div:nth-child(1):active{
  margin: 16px 0 0 28px;
  background: url(../images/active.png) no-repeat #1978b3;
  background-position: left 26px center;
}
```

```html
 <div class="sidebar">
    <div>
      <a class="sidebar_active" href="#">Новые общественные предложения</a>
    </div>
    <div>
     <a  class="sidebar_history" href="#">История</a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <a  class="sidebar_help" href="#">Помощь</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Возможно чтоб также с изменение текста изменялся и background? Например он сейчас белый, мы нажимаем на пункт меню меняется текст и бг  уже на синий?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
document.querySelector('a.sidebar_active').addEventListener('click', e => e.target.innerHTML = 'Пункт меню');
```

```css
.sidebar > div:nth-child(1){
  margin: 16px 0 0 28px;
  background: url(../images/Open_Book.png) no-repeat;
  background-position: left 26px center;
}

.sidebar > div:nth-child(1):active{
  margin: 16px 0 0 28px;
  background: url(../images/active.png) no-repeat #1978b3;
  background-position: left 26px center;
}
```

```html
 <div class="sidebar">
    <div>
      <a class="sidebar_active" href="#">Новые общественные предложения</a>
    </div>
    <div>
     <a  class="sidebar_history" href="#">История</a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <a  class="sidebar_help" href="#">Помощь</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вариант на чистом css

```css
[data-text]:before {
content: attr(data-text);
}
[data-text-active]:target:before {
content: attr(data-text-active);
background:#0af;
color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="sidebar">
    <div>
      <a class="sidebar_active" href="#this" id="this" data-text="Новые общественные предложения" data-text-active="Пункт"></a>
    </div>
    <div>
     <a  class="sidebar_history" href="#">История</a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <a  class="sidebar_help" href="#">Помощь</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.querySelector('.sidebar_active').addEventListener('click', () => {
  document.querySelector('.sidebar_active').innerHTML = 'Привет';
})
```

```css
.sidebar>div:nth-child(1) {
  margin: 16px 0 0 28px;
  background: url(../images/Open_Book.png) no-repeat;
  background-position: left 26px center;
}

.sidebar>div:nth-child(1):active {
  margin: 16px 0 0 28px;
  background: url(../images/active.png) no-repeat #1978b3;
  background-position: left 26px center;
}
```

```html
<div class="sidebar">
  <div>
    <a class="sidebar_active" href="#">Новые общественные предложения</a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <a class="sidebar_history" href="#">История</a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <a class="sidebar_help" href="#">Помощь</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Не советовал бы использовать onclick.

Comment: @Duoxx  почему? можно поподробней?

Comment: AddEventListener и RemoveEventListener позволяет более гибкое взаимодействие

Comment: @Duoxx Понятно, учту...